# A linear-time algorithm for finding the longest distance between two nodes in a free tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given a free tree, find an algorithm to find the longest path between two nodes that runs in linear time.  Is this possible to do if the nodes don't store their level? If yes, how?

If the nodes do store their level then I would move the lower node up the tree to the same level as the other. Than I would keep moving up the tree until the nodes overlap. The distance would be the sum of each time a node was moved up the tree.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what a free tree is, but can you use breadth first search from node a to find node b which is far from node a. then use breadth first search on node b to find node c which is far from b. the distance between b and c is the answer?

Comment: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the edges between the two nodes could not be used more than once, the path is fixed. So the problem is to find the lowest common ancestor, you can read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor
There's a famous algorithm to solve it, and it's here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm

Comment: How does LCA help here?  That supposes you already know the nodes to check.

Answer (score 0):

I solved http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PT07Z/ with the following code as an exercise to learn python:

```
def func(node):
    global M
    if (len(node)==0):
        return 0
    else:
        s=[func(nodes[n]) for n in node]
        s.sort()
        m1=s[-1]+1
        m2=0
        if len(s)>1:
            m2=s[-2]+1
        M=max(M,m1+m2)
        return m1

t=input()
nodes={}
for node in range(1,t+1):
    nodes[node]=[]
for i in range(t-1):
    s=raw_input().split()
    a,b=int(s[0]),int(s[1])
    nodes[a].append(b)

M=0
func(nodes[1])
print M
```

Note you can sort the nodes in linear time because you know the nodes go from 0 to N, so you move node 0 to position 0.. node 5 to position 5 etc.