# Minimising Number of Bridges in a Graph

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, graph, bridge

I was trying to solve a problem which basically reduces to this:
Give a set of **N** nodes numbered from 1 to N and **M** edges where **N<10000** and **M<100000**,                                               
Find **an Edge(u,v)** which when added to the graph -- **Minimizes the number of bridges in the graph**.
If there are many such edges - Print the one which has **lowest lexicographical value.**
What would be an *efficient* approach to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this problem is very hard. Here would be outline of the solution I can think of:

1) Find all bridges in graph.

2) Now imagine that bridges are the only edges you want in your graph. You only keep bridges and join all the nodes between bridges in big nodes.

3) You now have a tree. Edges are bridges, nodes are "big nodes" that combine nodes from previous graph.

4) Let's call this forest graph T.

5) Connecting any two nodes in graph T, creates a cycle. Any edge in the cycle is not a bridge.

6) Point 5 implies that solution is found by creating the longest cycle possible. You can do that simply by finding two nodes that have longest distance between them.

7) You can find nodes with longest distance in graph. How is discussed here:
[A linear-time algorithm for finding the longest distance between two nodes in a free tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797084/a-linear-time-algorithm-for-finding-the-longest-distance-between-two-nodes-in-a)

Let me know if any point needs further explanation.

Comment: I had arrived at a similar algorithm but I wasn't able to code it properly. It would be really helpful if you would explain with some code. The explanation was really awesome though!

Comment: The core idea looks good to me, but notice that the initial graph is not necessary connected. This means that at point 3 you might get a forest instead of a single tree.

Comment: @AnimeshFatehpuria Writting code for this problem will be brutal in all honesty. You can do point 3, by removing all bridges and than each connected component represents one node. You can do flood-fill algorithm to get those components. Than build graph from that. To solve point 6 I would try to explore that link.

Comment: Nice answer! For step 1, I suggest the following explanation of an efficient algorithm: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/

Comment: The bridges can be found efficiently using chain decomposition. See http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0700.pdf